# Angular Formly ui-grid and columnDefs

Tags: angular-ui-grid, angular-formly

Attempting to add `ui-grid` `columnDefs`.

http://jsbin.com/coqewo/edit?html,js,output

```
app.run(function(formlyConfig) {
  formlyConfig.setType({
    name: 'ui-grid',
    template: '<div ui-grid="{ data: model[options.key], columnDefs:[{name:name}, {name:abbr}] }" ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit></div>',
    wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError']
  });
});
```

What am I missing or should I be adding `columnDefs` elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

tuckerjt07 on https://gitter.im/formly-js/angular-formly# answered the question for me:

Template

```
template: '<div ui-grid="{ data: model[options.key], 
    columnDefs: to.columnDefs}" 
    ui-grid-auto-resize 
    ui-grid-pagination 
    ui-grid-selection 
    ui-grid-edit   
    ui-grid-row-edit</div>'
```

Javascript

```
vm.fields = [
  {
    key: 'list',
    type: 'ui-grid',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Simple UI Grid',
      columnDefs: columnDefs
    }
  }
];

var columnDefs;
columnDefs = [
  {
    name: 'State',
    field: 'name'
  },
  {
    name: 'Abbr',
    field: 'abbr'
  }
];
```